# Calling tries to lazy load in every properties getter

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I've inherited a class which has a bunch of properties defined as:

```
public int ID
{
    get { return m_nOID; }
    set { m_nOID = value; }
}

public int ConxnDetail
{
    get { LoadDetails(); return m_nConxnDetail; }
    set { m_nConxnDetail = value; }
}

public bool ConxnConstraints
{
    get { LoadDetails(); return m_bConxnConstraints; }
    set { m_bConxnConstraints = value; }
}

public bool IsShowCables
{
    get { LoadDetails(); return m_bIsShowCables; }
    set { m_bIsShowCables = value; }
}

public int DefaultQueue
{
    get { LoadDetails(); return m_nDefaultQueue; }
    set { m_nDefaultQueue = value; }
}

private User LoadDetails()
{
    if (!IsLoaded && !IsNew)
    {
        Logger.InfoFormat("Loading user details. UserID: [{0}]", m_nOID);
        User user = RemoteActivator.Create<RemoteUser>().GetUserById(m_nOID);
        if (user != null)
        {
            CopyDetails(user);
            MarkLoaded();
        }
        else
            ClearDetails();
    }
    return this;
}
```

I would absolutely love to clean up the conventions here a bit and use only automatic getters/setters. Is this possible to do? If not, any other suggestions on reducing the boilerplate needed?

Comment: Is there a reason the data isn't loaded when the object is constructed?

Comment: Retrieving the ID property does not incur loading of all details. I assume that this was an optimization made at some point to lazy-load everything except the ID.

Comment: @SeanAnderson What is your intention? To keep that optimization in or to remove it?

Comment: My intention is to not alter the function of the code, but to improve its readability. At the very least, is there a way to listen for properties being retrieved and execute LoadDetails only if the loading property isn't ID? This would allow me to replace all of this with automatic properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx) event handler, but I'm not sure why you would need that in this case?  Instead why not just load the details when the ID changes as that seems to be the only value that will change between LoadDetails calls.

Perhaps something like:

```
public int ID
{
    get { return m_nOID; }
    set {

       if(m_NOID != value) {
          InitialiseUserDetails(m_nOID);
       }

       m_nOID = value; 
    }
}
```

If this was ok, you could remove the private backing fields as I believe you wish to do.